# Defining the correct path to Twilio services directory

Tags: twilio-php

I don't have the ability to use composer to install twilio-php library so I am installing it manually.  It is very confusing for me as a nubie to understand how to initiate a new service...notice the first require **statement** it points to a directory of Services/Twilio.  After downloading the Twilio-Php library there is no directory named Services.  Also the $client= new Services Twilio will need the right path as well.  What do I do, Help?

```
<?php 
   require("Services/Twilio.php"); 
   require("database.php"); 

   // initiate phone call via Twilio REST API     
   // Set our AccountSid and AuthToken  
   $AccountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
   $AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 

   // Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client  
   $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [latest install instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) show the following:

```
 <?php
    // Require the bundled autoload file - the path may need to change
    // based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
    require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
```

In which directory did you unzip the library?